# Detect click events in Qt

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am inheriting `QQuickItem` to implement a custom 3D GL item.

I need to detect a `Click` event inside my `CustomItem` derived from `QQuickItem` (`Press` + `Release` with no `Move` in between). In the previous windowing framework I used to use, the `Click` event existed alongside the `Press`, `Move` and `Release` events.

In **Qt**, I cannot see any `Click` event defined inside [QQuickItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html).

Do I have to make-up the `Click` event for myself? i.e. when the `Release` and the `Press` occur at the same location, with no `Move` in between, I know I have a `Click`.

Or is there a `Click` already defined in **Qt**? I am asking because the `DoubleClick` is defined.

Comment: You may have a look at `MouseArea`.

Comment: I am inheriting **QQuickItem** to implement a custom 3D GL item, so **MouseArea** won't do. I have updated the post to make this clear.

Comment: You should implement it yourself using `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent`. You may have a look at the source code of `QQuickMouseArea` to see how Qt implemented it.

Comment: Thanks that's clear now.